# browsersync with static .html files - regex help needed

Tags: regex, redirect, gulp

I have static html files which have links like "/about" in it. For development i use gulp with browsersync and want that a link like "/about" is redirected internally to "/about.html".

I tried to add use modRewrite as middleware to browsersync and define a regex, so that all urls without file ending and trailing slash or without trailing slash are redirected to $1. But i can't get it work.

This rule would work, but i would need to define it for each page:

```
^(.+about)\/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Then i tried to define a rule like (when the file has no file ending, redirect it to html, but  this doesn't work:

```
(!\.html|\.js|\.css|\.png$)\/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: i added what i have tried so far...

Comment: Try [`^((?:(?!\.(?:html|js|css|png)\/?$).)*)$ $1.html [L]`](https://regex101.com/r/fE9sR9/1)

Comment: This works for links like http://localhost:9000/about but not for links with a trailing slash like http://localhost:9000/about/ and also not for the http://localhost:9000 (which points to the index.html) Maybe for the index.html i could add a second rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now came up with this two regex which work for me. These regex don't take all possible urls into account... I had problems using \w with modRewrite. But it works for me now and i will correct it in case i need it:

```
'^/$ /index.html [L]', 
'^(\/?(?!\.(?:html|js|css|png|jpg|svg)$)[a-z-]*   (?:\/+[a-z-]+)*)\/?$ $1.html [L]'
```

Answer (score 0):

In a completely different direction, I developed something a while back for a similar purpose.  It does dynamic modification of internal URLs using some pretty simple Javascript / jQuery code.

You can put the Javascript in a static .js file, then include jQuery from a CDN and include the Javascript code from your public directory.  Say that you call the file 'link-rewriter.js', you would use it like so from the .html files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/javascript/link-rewriter.js"></script>
```

The code for the link-rewriter looks like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var parser = document.createElement('a');
    parser.href = '/';

    var domain = parser.protocol + '//' + parser.host;
    var regexp = new RegExp('^' + escapeRegExp(domain), 'i');

    $('a[href^="http://"],a[href^="https://"],a[href^="//"]]').each(function(index, link) {
        var href = link['href'].replace(regexp, '');

        if ((!/^\//.test(href)) && (!/\.html$/i.test(href)) {
            link['href'] = link['href'] + '.html';
        }
    });
});
```

Breaking it down, this code starts by creating a prototype link (anchor) element that is used to query the protocol and host of the page, in order to define the domain.

Then, every *http*, *https*, and relative local link element is processed to see if it needs to be rewritten.  The processing code first strips out the webpage's domain, and leaves links that are either for another domain (or protocol) or for this domain.  The links for this domain are further processed to see which of them lack a .html extension, and those that are get the .html extension added automatically.

The upsides to this approach:

- simply adding to  tags to a page will upgrade the links in place
- it is blazingly fast, so the user will never notice it happening, even with thousands (!!) of links on the page
- only links for the same domain are modified, and even specific groups of links could be targeted

The downsides to this approach:

- The user must be have Javascript enabled in their browser (really, who doesn't these days??)
- This is code, so it may eventually require maintenance or feature enhancements

Comment: Thanks for your approach, in case i become problems with modRewrite i will switch back to your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution without the need of modRewrite. The [serve-static](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve-static) package can do all the hard work for you. Giving you the option to specify a extension to look for when the requested file isn't found.

```
var serveStatic = require('serve-static')

gulp.task('server', function() {
    return browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: '/',
            middleware: [
                serveStatic('/', { extensions: ['html'] })
            ]
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried this and it works only for paths like http://localhost:9000/. http://localhost:9000/work/ doesn't work. Should this work?

Comment: [link](localhost:9000/work) paths is indeed what works. So [link](localhost:9000/work) looks up `/work.html` in my example